# Where can I find description of RedPitaya fpga pin mapping?

Tags: documentation, fpga, xilinx, redpitaya

And manual for Xilinx ISE developing for it.
At redpitaya [wiki](http://wiki.redpitaya.com/index.php?title=FPGA_development_environment) only few words about FPGA development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to Xilinx tools you will either need PlanAhead (not ISE) or you move on to Vivado ...
From there on you can on the one hand side look into the source code and script that you get from the repository or you just open up a new project - put into xps or vivado a zynq ip and get the rest of the system together ...
With repect to code I prefer to write basic testing code in SDK for new IP (especialy custom IP) and transfer it lateron to Linux ...

The pinmapping can be found in the ucf-file in the repository for Planahead or Vivado (whether you prefer old school xilinx style or synopsys-style as in Vivado)

I would recommend just to download the repositiory - go to the fpga folder and open the project with PlanAhead or Vivado - here you will find the pin mapping and also settings for the PS (which you can export from here to other projects as well ...)

Comment: OK, I found some signals in .ucf, but how can I understand whole communication dependency? If there are any documentation for DAC/ADC and memory, any datasheets? Or I must use magnifying glass to identify chip and search datasheets by ID number?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm also waiting for the release of the schematics !!! 
The guys from Redpitaya posted some days ago that they are reviewing them - well guys - I think you did the board with them - the board works - so release them to the people who need them !!! ;)

With respect to your question I would recommend as a first approach to take a deep look at red_pitaya_analog.v . There is everything instantiated that is needed to understand how the current ecosystem works with regard to the analog frontend.
I 'm currently using this code - in order to transfer it to a stripped down (PLL remains, ...) VHDL version (a must in my project ;) in order to attach a DDS block to the DAC, and to fit the output of the ADC into an AXI-stream with some DSP stuff (including decimation filters in order to adapt sample rate - maybe also useful for you if you don't want the fixed 125MSPS rate) to the output of the ADC and a DMA-transfer to the memory of the PS ...
I think you should be capable to do the same - let me know if you are missing something ...

P.S.: With respect to analog performance you might get "a first impression" (noise, ...) from the hardware spec pdf ...

P.P.S.: If you already should have identified the DAC and the ADC (I haven't as they are still below the heat sink - that I haven't removed until now) - please feel free to post it here ! ;)

-> 20.3.2014 :

The ADC seems to be LTs LTC2145-14

http://www.linear.com/product/LTC2145-14

and the DAC seems to be NXPs DAC1401D125

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/DAC1401D125.pdf

Hope it helps ...